# Медиазапрос не принимает аргументом глобальную переменную

Tags: scss, зависимости

В частности, речь идёт о банальной установке размера шрифта в зависимости от ширины экрана.

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Если в этот код аргументом вместо 500px вставить глобальную переменную var(--mobile), то работать не будет. При этом её же вставляя для font-size - работает, то есть переменная определена правильно. Если определить локальную переменную в этом же файле и её использовать аргументом для медиазапроса - тоже всё работает. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

CSS переменные не работают в медиа запросах как аргумент.

Можно посмотреть в сторону использования scss/sass:

```
$breakpoint-mobile: 500px;

@media (max-width: $breakpoint-mobile) {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```